# Alias de data vencida no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma `query select` que recebe a data do usuário no banco de dados `MySQL` e o formato do campo é `datetime`, e o `PHP` trata a saída e no HTML dados como data de cadastro de um plano de consumo pessoal e quando o plano irá expirar, gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma alias para uma subquery que retorna a string "EXPIRADO" se a data de expiração do registro for 1 dia ou superior a ela.

A query atual está assim.

> SELECT `data_cad`,`data_expira`,`pl_nome` FROM `pl_misc` WHERE `pl_id`
>   = $xyz LIMIT 1;

Gostaria de ter algo como `AS EXPIRADO` que pudesse retornar no PHP com um `echo`. quero mesmo saber se tinha como imprimir ex: $row['expirado'] e imprimir "Expirado", "Não expirado", entende, condição  de IF e ELSE dentro do próprio MySQL.

Comment: Eliseu, achei uma função na documentação do php que talvez possa lhe ajudar. Por favor, veja se a função DateTime::diff te ajuda. Link: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @RodrigoTognin queria mesmo saber se com IF, ELSE ou qualquer outro modo dentro do próprio  MySQL seria possível , até  mesmo pra futuramente rodar a query direto no phpmyadmin capiche.

Comment: Eliseu, respondi a pouco outro usuário com um comando que pode te ajudar. Estarei colocando o código como exemplo na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliseu, o uso do Case When talvez te ajude. Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(data_expira, CURDATE()) < 0 THEN "Expirado" 
   ELSE data_expira END as Data
FROM pl_misc WHERE pl_id = $xyz LIMIT 1;
```

A ideia minha é pegar a data atual e comparar com a data de expiração. Se a data atual for maior que a data de expiração, mostra "Expirado".

Comment: #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'varchar, getdate(), 110) as data, CASE WHEN data > `data_expira` THEN 'expira' na linha 1.

Comment: Confere os campos, os nomes estão certos, a tabela também, mas retorna o erro.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo no meu mysql aqui, vou alterar o código da resposta.

Comment: Entendi a lógica, interessante fera, obrigado por isso, agora posso usar direto no phpmyadmin. tmj

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo apoio, Eliseu! Eu também aprendi com isso indo atrás das funções para montar a consulta!